# Access image file from home screen

Tags: images, home-screen-shortcuts, home-screen

I have Nexus 4 on Android 5.1.1, and I also have an image file with screenshot of my timetable. I'm trying to create a shortcut to it from the home screen.

I've tried 4 separate apps that claim to be able to do this, but all of them crashed.

Is there any way I can create this shortcut?

Comment: Are you trying to create the shortcut on the home screen? If that's the case then which launcher are you using? Could you mention the name or link of the four apps that you tried, so that the users don't end up suggesting them to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I bought a new phone (Nexus 5x) and [Shortcut Image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.windbellrrr.widget.shortcutimage) now works for me.

Answer (score 11):

Using Google Drive:

1. Upload the photo to Google Drive
2. Open the Drive app and open the photo
3. Open the triple dots menu in the top right
4. Scroll down
5. Select "Add to Home screen"

Optionally, set the photo in Drive to be available offline. (Thanks @nealmcb!)

Comment: Strangely, I don't see "Add to home screen" when opening the three dots.
Samsung S10e with ADW launcher and Android 12.

Comment: This worked for me on a Pixel device. I guess Samsungs it might not work.

Comment: Still works on Google devices like a Pixel 7 pro. I also specified in the same menu that the file be available offline. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you have a Samsung device, go to Files and find the picture. Then long press to select it, click "More" on the bottom, then click "Add to home screen".

Answer (score 1):

As [commented above by Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119000/access-image-file-from-home-screen#comment147204_119000), the launcher is important.

In Apex Launcher, if I add a widget for Gallery app, I can select a single image and the selected will be displayed as a 3x3 widget.

Answer (score 1):

To add a shortcut of a picture to your home screen, there's no app needed on the Samsung Android:

Go to 'My Files' (not Gallery).  Find the picture you want to add to your home screen.   Long Press on that picture (a checkmark will appear over it).  On the top right of your screen click on the 3 dots icon.  Select "Add to Home Screen".

This method is similar to that listed in [an earlier post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/233994), but some minor things have been changed in the OS to create this shortcut (probably due to a software update).  This is current as of May 2021

Answer (score 0):

For people who are searching to display all pictures from an images folder, there is also this app : [Nice Simple Photo Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nullium.nicesimplephotowidget)